# Angular8 and webpack4 : Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor_lib is not defined & source map error

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I'm working on a quite basic interface that was originally written in Angular2. I'm new to Angular2 and even more to webpack

I've done the migration from Angular2.4 to Angular8.0

I've also migrated to webpack2.2.0 to webpack4.33.0
(Thanks to the tutorial we can find)

It is now building when doing : npm run build:dev

But when I launch my chrome page I got this error :

```
bootstrap:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor_lib is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap:2)
    at i (bootstrap:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap:2)
    at i (bootstrap:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (a11y.es5.js:27)
    at i (bootstrap:2)
    at Module.<anonymous> (bootstrap:2)
    at i (bootstrap:2)
    at o (bootstrap:2)
    at bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:2
i @ bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:2
i @ bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ a11y.es5.js:27
i @ bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:2
i @ bootstrap:2
o @ bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:2

bootstrap:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor_lib is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap:2)
    at r (bootstrap:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap:2)
    at r (bootstrap:2)
    at Module.<anonymous> (bootstrap:2)
    at r (bootstrap:2)
    at o (bootstrap:2)
    at bootstrap:2
    at bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:2
r @ bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:2
r @ bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:2
r @ bootstrap:2
o @ bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:2
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:2
```

and when looking to that bootstrap:2, I got :

```
     // install a JSONP callback for chunk loading
     function webpackJsonpCallback(data) { <====ERROR at this line
         var chunkIds = data[0];
         var moreModules = data[1];
         var executeModules = data[2];

         // add "moreModules" to the modules object,
         // then flag all "chunkIds" as loaded and fire callback
         var moduleId, chunkId, i = 0, resolves = [];
         for(;i < chunkIds.length; i++) {
             chunkId = chunkIds[i];
             if(installedChunks[chunkId]) {
                 resolves.push(installedChunks[chunkId][0]);
             }
             installedChunks[chunkId] = 0;
         }
...
```

I've look on every post that seemed to be the same error.
I either had dead link sometimes, or it didn't work when changing my webpack config (putting vendors to null for example)

I must admit that "vendor_lib" doesn't really echoed to me, and I didn't find real explanation about what it could be and even if it's really linked to webpack

This is the webpack.dev.config.js file

```
const DllBundlesPlugin = require('webpack-dll-bundles-plugin').DllBundlesPlugin;

module.exports = function (options) {
    return webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {
        devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
        entry : {
            vendor: []
        },
        output: {
            path: helpers.root('dist'),
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
            sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
            chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
            library: 'ac_[name]',
            libraryTarget: 'var',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                    include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                    include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
                },
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new DefinePlugin({
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
                'process.env': {
                    'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                    'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
                }
            }),
            new DllBundlesPlugin({
                bundles: {
                    polyfills: [
                        'core-js',
                        {
                            name: 'zone.js',
                            path: 'zone.js/dist/zone.js'
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'zone.js',
                            path: 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js'
                        },
                        'ts-helpers',
                    ],
                    vendor: [
                        '@angular/platform-browser',
                        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
                        '@angular/core',
                        '@angular/common',
                        '@angular/forms',
                        '@angular/http',
                        '@angular/router',
                        '@angularclass/hmr',
                        'rxjs',
                    ]
                },
                dllDir: helpers.root('dll'),
                webpackConfig: webpackMergeDll(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {
                    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
                    plugins: []
                })
            }),
            new AddAssetHtmlPlugin(
                [{ filepath: helpers.root(`dll/${DllBundlesPlugin.resolveFile('polyfills')}`) },
                 { filepath: helpers.root(`dll/${DllBundlesPlugin.resolveFile('vendor')}`) }]
            ),
            new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                debug: true,
                options: {
                }
            }),
        ],
        devServer: {
            port: METADATA.port,
            host: METADATA.host,
            historyApiFallback: true,
            watchOptions: {
                aggregateTimeout: 300,
                poll: 1000
            }
        },
        node: {
            global: true,
            crypto: 'empty',
            process: true,
            module: false,
            clearImmediate: false,
            setImmediate: false
        }
    });
}
```

@edit :

So, after some research, I've found a new message error when running on firefox :

```
Source map error: TypeError: Invalid URL: webpack://ac_[name]/webpack/bootstrap
Resource URL: http://localhost:9090/polyfills.bundle.js
Source Map URL: polyfills.bundle.js.map
Source map error: TypeError: Invalid URL: webpack://ac_[name]/webpack/bootstrap
Resource URL: http://localhost:9090/main.bundle.js
Source Map URL: main.bundle.js.map
```

It seems like the polyfills.bundle.js and main.bundle.js are both served and reachable.

So it seems like the problem come from the configuration file.
Does anyone know from where this error come from ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I won't be able to help you with your webpack issues.

In your case I would try to create a [Angular-CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) project from scratch and then incrementally copy the source to the project.

The Angular-CLI project hides and manages the webpack configuration for you internally. You don't even see it. If it is a basic application without special needs, this procedure should be sufficient.

Greetings Chris

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm gonna do this.
But I'd really like to understand the error anyway !